# How to Make Tikz Representation of This 3d Image with Overlay

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I have the below image to represent with tikz in four levels instead of five:

[image: The image I want to mimic]

I want level 4 to appear first, then level 4 with level 3, then level 4, level3 with level 2, then level 4, level 3, level 2, with level 1 in for frames. If you do not mind for all my overlay to be in a single frame.

I want different levels with unique colour fill with a black border.

I only want level 4 to level 1.

`Discription` should be `Description` instead.

Here is what I am trying:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
    
    
        \begin{itemize}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Level $4$ \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (L1) {};
        \end{itemize}
                \item Level 3 $3$ \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (L2) {};
                \item Level 2 $2$ \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (L3) {};
                \item Level 1 $1$ \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (L4) {};
    \end{itemize}
%\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    %\path[->] (L4) edge [bend right] (d1);
    %\path[->] (L3) edge [bend right] (d2);
    %\path[->] (L2) edge [out=0, in=-90] (d3);
    %\path[->] (L1) edge [out=0, in=-90] (d4);
%\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "Discription" should be "Description".

Comment: I am not sure, I understand your question. Do you want the entire image in tikz and make each layer and the descriptive text appear OR is the image there and you only want the descriptive text to appear?

Comment: @MarkusG. I want the entire image in tilkz and each layer and the descriptive text appear

Comment: I don't really understand the image; are the tiles supposed to float at definite heights?  Because they don't give the impression of laying on a horizontal plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

One solution is to use the command `\draw<n> ...` which creates the corresponding graphical element on the `n` layer of the current frame.

- I change the light on the bricks to give a slight impression of reality.
- The bricks' dimensions are controlled (by predictable variables) at the beginning of the `tikzpicture` environment.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\xdefinecolor{O}{RGB}{255, 102, 17}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test with bricks}
  \centering
  \tikzmath{
    real \e1, \e2, \e3, \e4, \w1, \w2, \w3, \w4;
    \e1 = 5;
    \e2 = 4;
    \e3 = 3;
    \e4 = 1.6;
    \w1 = 1.7;
    \w2 = \w1*\e2/\e1;
    \w3 = \w1*\e3/\e1;
    \w4 = \w1*\e4/\e1;
  }
  \hspace{-2cm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=3cm, overlay, scale=.9]
    \draw<1-5> (-3, -2.5) rectangle (5.5, 5.5);

    % first tile
    \draw<5>[fill=O!70!black] (0, 0, \e1) -- (\w1, 0, \e1)
    -- (\w1, \e1, \e1) -- (0, \e1, \e1) -- cycle;
    \draw<5>[fill=O!70] (0, \e1, \e1) -- (\w1, \e1, \e1)
    -- (\w1, \e1, 0) -- (0, \e1, 0) -- cycle;
    \draw<5>[fill=O] (\w1, 0, \e1) -- (\w1, \e1, \e1)
    -- (\w1, \e1, 0) -- (\w1, 0, 0) -- cycle;
    
    % second tile
    \draw<4-5>[fill=O!70!black] (\w1+0, 0, \e2) -- (\w1+\w2, 0, \e2)
    -- (\w1+\w2, \e2, \e2) -- (\w1+0, \e2, \e2) -- cycle;
    \draw<4-5>[fill=O!70] (\w1+0, \e2, \e2) -- (\w1+\w2, \e2, \e2)
    -- (\w1+\w2, \e2, 0) -- (\w1+0, \e2, 0) -- cycle;
    \draw<4-5>[fill=O] (\w1+\w2, 0, \e2) -- (\w1+\w2, \e2, \e2)
    -- (\w1+\w2, \e2, 0) -- (\w1+\w2, 0, 0) -- cycle;

    % third tile
    \draw<3-5>[fill=O!70!black] (\w1+\w2+0, 0, \e3) -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, 0, \e3)
    -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, \e3, \e3) -- (\w1+\w2+0, \e3, \e3) -- cycle;
    \draw<3-5>[fill=O!70] (\w1+\w2+0, \e3, \e3) -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, \e3, \e3)
    -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, \e3, 0) -- (\w1+\w2+0, \e3, 0) -- cycle;
    \draw<3-5>[fill=O] (\w1+\w2+\w3, 0, \e3) -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, \e3, \e3)
    -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, \e3, 0) -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, 0, 0) -- cycle;

    % fourth tile
    \draw<2-5>[fill=O!70!black] (\w1+\w2+\w3+0, 0, \e4)
    -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, 0, \e4)
    -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, \e4, \e4)
    -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+0, \e4, \e4) -- cycle;
    \draw<2-5>[fill=O!70] (\w1+\w2+\w3+0, \e4, \e4)
    -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, \e4, \e4)
    -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, \e4, 0)
    -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+0, \e4, 0) -- cycle;
    \draw<2-5>[fill=O] (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, 0, \e4)
    -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, \e4, \e4)
    -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, \e4, 0)
    -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, 0, 0) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Further modification by OP:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\xdefinecolor{O}{rgb}{0.85, 1.0, 0.3}
\xdefinecolor{OO}{rgb}{0.67, 1.0, 0.3}
\xdefinecolor{OOO}{rgb}{0.43, 1.0, 0.3}
\xdefinecolor{OOOO}{rgb}{0.27, 1.0, 0.3}
\begin{document}


    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test with bricks}
        \centering
        \tikzmath{
            real \e1, \e2, \e3, \e4, \w1, \w2, \w3, \w4;
            \e1 = 5;
            \e2 = 4;
            \e3 = 3;
            \e4 = 1.6;
            \w1 = 1.7;
            \w2 = \w1*\e2/\e1;
            \w3 = \w1*\e3/\e1;
            \w4 = \w1*\e4/\e1;
        }
        \hspace{-2cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=3cm, overlay, scale=.9]
            \draw<1-5> (-3, -2.5) rectangle (5.5, 5.5);
        
            % first tile
            \draw<5>[fill=OOOO!70!black] (0, 0, \e1) -- (\w1, 0, \e1)
            -- (\w1, \e1, \e1) -- (0, \e1, \e1) -- cycle;
            \draw<5>[fill=OOOO!70] (0, \e1, \e1) -- (\w1, \e1, \e1)
            -- (\w1, \e1, 0) -- (0, \e1, 0) -- cycle;
            \draw<5>[fill=OOOO] (\w1, 0, \e1) -- (\w1, \e1, \e1)
            -- (\w1, \e1, 0) -- (\w1, 0, 0) -- cycle;
        
            % second tile
            \draw<4-5>[fill=OOO!70!black] (\w1+0, 0, \e2) -- (\w1+\w2, 0, \e2)
            -- (\w1+\w2, \e2, \e2) -- (\w1+0, \e2, \e2) -- cycle;
            \draw<4-5>[fill=OOO!70] (\w1+0, \e2, \e2) -- (\w1+\w2, \e2, \e2)
            -- (\w1+\w2, \e2, 0) -- (\w1+0, \e2, 0) -- cycle;
            \draw<4-5>[fill=OOO] (\w1+\w2, 0, \e2) -- (\w1+\w2, \e2, \e2)
            -- (\w1+\w2, \e2, 0) -- (\w1+\w2, 0, 0) -- cycle;
        
            % third tile
            \draw<3-5>[fill=OO!70!black] (\w1+\w2+0, 0, \e3) -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, 0, \e3)
            -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, \e3, \e3) -- (\w1+\w2+0, \e3, \e3) -- cycle;
            \draw<3-5>[fill=OO!70] (\w1+\w2+0, \e3, \e3) -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, \e3, \e3)
            -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, \e3, 0) -- (\w1+\w2+0, \e3, 0) -- cycle;
            \draw<3-5>[fill=OO] (\w1+\w2+\w3, 0, \e3) -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, \e3, \e3)
            -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, \e3, 0) -- (\w1+\w2+\w3, 0, 0) -- cycle;
        
            % fourth tile
            \draw<2-5>[fill=O!70!black] (\w1+\w2+\w3+0, 0, \e4)
            -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, 0, \e4)
            -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, \e4, \e4)
            -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+0, \e4, \e4) -- cycle;
            \draw<2-5>[fill=O!70] (\w1+\w2+\w3+0, \e4, \e4)
            -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, \e4, \e4)
            -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, \e4, 0)
            -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+0, \e4, 0) -- cycle;
            \draw<2-5>[fill=O] (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, 0, \e4)
            -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, \e4, \e4)
            -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, \e4, 0)
            -- (\w1+\w2+\w3+\w4, 0, 0) -- cycle;
        
        \node <5> [below] at (-1.25,3.1) {\huge R};
        \node <5> [below] at (-1.25,2.05) {\huge A};
        \node <5> [below] at (-1.25,1.0) {\huge T};
        \node <5> [below] at (-1.25,-0.05) {\huge I};
        \node <5> [below] at (-1.25,-1.1) {\huge O};
        
        \node <4-5> [below] at (0.75,2.45) {\large I};
        \node <4-5> [below] at (0.75,2.05) {\large N};
        \node <4-5> [below] at (0.75,1.55) {\large T};
        \node <4-5> [below] at (0.75,1.05) {\large E};
        \node <4-5> [below] at (0.75,0.55) {\large R};
        \node <4-5> [below] at (0.75,0.05) {\large V};
        \node <4-5> [below] at (0.75,-0.45) {\large A};
        \node <4-5> [below] at (0.75,-0.9) {\large L};
        
        \node <3-5> [below] at (2.3,1.8) {\normalsize O};
        \node <3-5> [below] at (2.3,1.4) {\normalsize R};
        \node <3-5> [below] at (2.3,1.0) {\normalsize D};
        \node <3-5> [below] at (2.3,0.6) {\normalsize I};
        \node <3-5> [below] at (2.3,0.2) {\normalsize N};
        \node <3-5> [below] at (2.3,-0.2) {\normalsize A};
        \node <3-5> [below] at (2.3,-0.6) {\normalsize L};
        
        \node <2-5> [below] at (3.7,1.1) {\footnotesize N};
        \node <2-5> [below] at (3.7,0.83) {\footnotesize O};
        \node <2-5> [below] at (3.7,0.63) {\footnotesize M};
        \node <2-5> [below] at (3.7,0.4) {\footnotesize I};
        \node <2-5> [below] at (3.7,0.2) {\footnotesize N};
        \node <2-5> [below] at (3.7,0.0) {\footnotesize A};
        \node <2-5> [below] at (3.7,-0.225) {\footnotesize L};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer is great, it remains `labelling` and `description with `arrows`. `Each layer` has to have its `unique colour`.

Comment: Yes, I have separated the colour to my taste. I am working on the labels and description.

Answer (score 2):

While the answer by @daniel-n is of course by far superiour in terms of staying true to the original image with the 3D effect, I would like to point out, that the answer is also quite complicated as a result of the poor 3D capabilities of tikz. Typically 3D does also not carry additional information, so in terms of style I would generally advise against using 3D effects unless they are required by the use-case in question.

Here is an answer using a 2D pyramid (based off of [the answer by Daniel N.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591755/118712)):

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \centering
        \tikzmath{
            real \h1, \h2, \h3, \h4, \w1, \w2, \w3, \w4, \f1;
            \h4 = 0.8;
            \h3 = 1.25*\h4;
            \h2 = 1.5*\h4;
            \h1 = 1.75*\h4;
            \w4 = 4*\h4;
            \w3 = 5*\h4;
            \w2 = 6*\h4;
            \w1 = 7*\h4;
            \t = \h1+\h2+\h3+\h4;
        }
        \begin{tikzpicture}[pyramidblock/.style={rectangle,draw=black,thick,anchor=south},descriptdot/.style={circle,fill,minimum height=1.5mm,inner sep=0},arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}]
            \path (-0.5*\w1,0) -- (2.5*\w1,1.5\t);
            \node<5->[pyramidblock,fill=red,   minimum width=\w4 cm,minimum height=\h4 cm] (P4) at (P3.north) {Layer 4};
            \node<5->[] (D4) at (7/8*\w1,\t*1.25) {Descriptor 4};
            \draw<5->[arrow] (P4.east) to[out=0,in=180] (D4.west) node[descriptdot] at (P4.east) {};
            
            \node<4->[pyramidblock,fill=blue,  minimum width=\w3 cm,minimum height=\h3 cm] (P3) at (P2.north) {Layer 3};
            \node<4->[] (D3) at (7/8*\w1,\t*.75) {Descriptor 3};
            \draw<4->[arrow] (P3.east) to[out=0,in=180] (D3.west) node[descriptdot] at (P3.east) {};
            
            \node<3->[pyramidblock,fill=green, minimum width=\w2 cm,minimum height=\h2 cm] (P2) at (P1.north) {Layer 2};
            \node<3->[] (D2) at (7/8*\w1,\t*.25) {Descriptor 2};
            \draw<3->[arrow] (P2.east) to[out=0,in=180] (D2.west) node[descriptdot] at (P2.east) {};
            
            \node<2->[pyramidblock,fill=yellow,minimum width=\w1 cm,minimum height=\h1 cm] (P1) at (0,0)     {Layer 1};
            \node<2->[] (D1) at (7/8*\w1,-\t*0.25) {Descriptor 1};
            \draw<2->[arrow] (P1.east) to[out=0,in=180] (D1.west) node[descriptdot] at (P1.east) {};        
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: gif of the beamer presentation with animation]